# Calculate random scores

Tags: javascript, random

I am developing a game and whenever a player finishes a level I want him to win some points. After 100 rounds the user must have won exact 1000 points but I dont want him to just win 10points per round because that would be boring. How can I add some randomness to this situation? Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Is that even possible?`, yes, of course it is. What have you tried?

Comment: And just how do you want the scores distributed? Presumably you don't want to end up with `901` points in round 1 and then only get `1` point for every subsequent round. Maybe take the `1000 - currentScore` divide it by the number of rounds remaining and then roll a random number between half that result and twice that result. So for round one you'll get a number between `5` and `20`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, but it is probably unnecessary. There are many crude ways to get a score that is CLOSE to 1000 after 100 rounds. If the players score is higher than (10*roundNumber) award 5-10 points. If it is less award 10-15. This is just one example of a crude way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a million and one ways to add an element of randomness to a score; but to offer some constructive advice, you need to provide some more information about your ideas on the scoring, so that it's a little more clear as to what you're trying to achieve.

You could just add/subtract a random value from 10; keep a running total and make adjustments to the random number generator as you progress through levels; but without a clear expectation of your scoring, players are probably going to be deterred.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example. This function will produce a random number between min and max.

```
function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

**edit:**

And then you can use that to randomly fill an array so that the total sum comes out as 1000.

```
var pointsPerRound = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) pointsPerRound[i] = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) pointsPerRound[randomInt(0, 100)]++;
```

Comment: This doesn't really help at all, yeah it may _Slightly_ ease the code once the initial problem is solved, but until then, this is of no use. Sorry.